# Snowball Stemming: defining Null Region

Tags: nlp, stemming, linguistics, porter-stemmer, snowball

I'm trying to understand the snowball stemming algorithmus. [HW90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848056/snowball-stemming-defining-regions) has had a similar question with examples, but not mine. The algorithmus is using two regions R1 and R2 that are definied as follows:

> R1 is the region after the first non-vowel following a vowel, or is
>   the null region at the end of the word if there is no such non-vowel.
>
> R2 is the region after the first non-vowel following a vowel in R1, or
>   is the null region at the end of the word if there is no such
>   non-vowel.
>
> http://snowball.tartarus.org/texts/r1r2.html

I don't understand, what "the null region at the end of the word" is. Could anybody give me some examples for that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null region means empty region, no letters. You missed the examples in the [documentation page](http://snowball.tartarus.org/texts/r1r2.html):

> Below, R1 and R2 are shown for a number of English words,
>
> ```
> b   e   a   u   t   i   f   u   l
>                   |<------------->|    R1
>                           |<----->|    R2
> ```
>
> Letter t is the first non-vowel following a vowel in beautiful, so R1
>   is iful. In iful, the letter f is the first non-vowel following a
>   vowel, so R2 is ul.
>
> ```
> b   e   a   u   t   y
>                   |<->|    R1
>                     ->|<-  R2
> ```
>
> In beauty, the last letter y is classed as a vowel. Again, letter t is the first non-vowel following a
>   vowel, so R1 is just the last letter, y. R1 contains no non-vowel, so
>   R2 is the null region at the end of the word.
>
> ```
> b   e   a   u
>             ->|<-  R1
>             ->|<-  R2
> ```